# MQTT with arduino(using ESP8266), Node js server and Android app

Tags: node.js, push-notification, arduino, mqtt, esp8266

I have an application that sends data from an Arduino (using ESP8266) to a Node.js server. I want to use mqtt for push notification on Android when sensors are not normal. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to explain what you have already tried